# wsgi: No module named 'settings'

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, wsgi

I have installed apache2 and wsgi on my Ubuntu16.4
I got this error;

```
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

In my Django project folder, there is the directory named 'settings' and inside 'settings' folder, several settings files like `default.py, development.py,...` exist. 
Inside `wsgi_dev.py`, the setting is done for wsgi.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",'settings.development')
```

This settings folder is not recognized as module. I have `__init__.py` inside settings folder.

```
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup` 
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in getattr
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in init
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in find_and_load`
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Comment: You haven’t shown your project layout or Apache config, so we can only guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your `wsgi.py`

```
    import os
    import sys
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings.development'
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.development")
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the outer project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`) is on the Python path, so you have to include the project name when setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. For example:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'mysite.settings.development')
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. So I have written full error messages.